# Postgres trigger with IF conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `test.import` with triggers which are work well in case when   `invoice_usd`inserted with

```
INSERT INTO test.imports(
import_id, supplier_id, date, rate, invoice_usd, freight, vat, duty, other)
VALUES (1, 'KR01', '2020-10-10', 1.2111, 36234, 550, 6345, 213, 123);

 |import_id|supplier_id|date      |rate  |invoice_usd|invoice_eur|freight|vat    |duty  | other|total_costs|summary_import|costs_per_euro|
 |---------|-----------|----------|--  --|-----------|-----------|-------|-------|------|------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
 |1        |KR01       |2020-10-10|1.2111|36234.00   |29918.26   |550.00 |6345.00|213.00|123.00|7231.00    |37149.26.     |0.2417        |
```

But, when I insert statement without `invoice_usd` and `rate` `VALUES` by using direct insert of `invoice_eur` value

```
INSERT INTO test.imports(
import_id, supplier_id, date, invoice_eur, freight, vat, duty, other)
VALUES (2, 'IT01', '2020-10-10', 5999, 550, 6345, 213, 123);

 |import_id|supplier_id|date      |rate|invoice_usd|invoice_eur|freight|vat    |duty  |other |total_costs|summary_import|costs_per_euro|
 |---------|-----------|----------|----|-----------|-----------|-------|-------|------|------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
 |2        |IT01       |2020-10-10|null|     null  |    null   |550.00 |6345.00|213.00|123.00|7231.00    |null          |null          |
```

In this case trigger  of course not work and finally I have null values not only in `invoice_usd` and `rate` but also in all dependant columns.

```
CREATE TABLE test.imports
(
import_id integer NOT NULL,
supplier_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
date date,
rate numeric(10,4),
invoice_usd numeric(10,2),
invoice_eur numeric(10,2),
freight numeric(10,2),
vat numeric(10,2),
duty numeric(10,2),
other numeric(10,2),
total_costs numeric(10,2),
summary_import numeric(10,2),
costs_per_euro numeric(10,4),
CONSTRAINT supply_pkey PRIMARY KEY (import_id)
)

CREATE TRIGGER tr_conv_invoice
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF invoice_usd
ON test.imports
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.f_conv_import_usd();

CREATE FUNCTION test.f_conv_import_usd()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE test.imports
SET invoice_eur = invoice_usd / rate;
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_expenses
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF freight, vat, duty, other
ON test.imports
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.f_total_costs();

CREATE TRIGGER tr_one_euro_expenses
AFTER UPDATE OF total_costs
ON test.imports
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.f_one_euro_expenses();
```

I try to modify trigger function `test.f_conv_import_usd()` with use `IF....ELSE IF` and create `test.f_conv_import_euro`

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.f_conv_import_euro()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
--SELECT invoice_usd
PERFORM invoice_usd
FROM test.imports
WHERE invoice_usd IS NULL;
IF FOUND
THEN
INSERT into test.imports (invoice_eur)
VALUES (invoice_euro);
ELSIF invoice_usd IS NOT NULL
THEN
UPDATE test.imports
SET invoice_eur = invoice_usd / rate;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END
```

and repeat this statement

```
INSERT INTO test.imports(
import_id, supplier_id, date, invoice_eur, freight, vat, duty, other)
VALUES (2, 'IT01', '2020-10-10', 5999, 550, 6345, 213, 123);
```

that generated ERROR:

```
ERROR:  column "invoice_eur" does not exist
LINE 2: VALUES (invoice_eur)
            ^
HINT:  There is a column named "invoice_eur" in table "imports", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
QUERY:  INSERT into test.imports (invoice_eur)
VALUES (invoice_eur)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test.f_conv_import_euro() line 9 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42703
```

Please advise how to refer to statement `INSERT` value of `invoice_eur` in this case?

Comment: You need to qualify the column, with either `old.` or `new.` (and `old` is undefined for insert queries)

Comment: If you want to modify the values being inserted use a `BEFORE` trigger and modify `NEW`.

Comment: Your triggers also update **all** rows of the table each time you insert or update a **single** row. I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ... I understand that it update all rows, but this will be solved later by adding `WHERE import_id=X` ,,, at the moment I need to clarify data from `invoice_eur` to insert it into `test.import` in case if columns `invoice_usd` and `rate` are omitted in `INSERT` statement

Comment: You already have the template for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65286820/second-trigger-result-disappear/65310557?noredirect=1#comment115463316_65310557) And again doing math on `NULL` values is going to return `NULL`.